# Error when I try to show cells from a Static TableView inside a ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2, containers

I have a problem with these lines and idk how to solve it.

So, I'm including a static UITableView in a ViewController through a Container. Into the TableViewController, I designed 2 cells which I want to show in the app (here the view:)

---

[image]

---

But, when I run the app... it gives this error:

---

[image]

---

Here are the lines of code I used:

---

class PhoneInputDataTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var menuItems = ["cellMobilePhone", "cellMobilePhone"]

@IBOutlet var mobileNumberTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("listOfCountriesSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(menuItems[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "text"
    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let select = segue.destinationViewController as? ListOfCountriesViewController {
        self.mobileNumberTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    }
}
```

---

** Where is my error? And, how I can solve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: do you have a custom class for that cell? do you set in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes... i put the respective identifier in the storyBoard, for both cells. @EugeneGordin

Comment: Have you checked that there is no typo in the storyboard's `identifier` field? Does it really say `cellMobilePhone` there?